# How to get local path for payload in WiX/Burn Managed Bootstrapper Application?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I am currently working in a WiX/Burn Managed Bootstrapper Application and cannot figure out how to get the local path for a payload (MSI).

I let the user select which applications they want to install in my custom UI, and I want to **not** show applications for which the MSI is missing. I also need to see information in the MSI's database.

I know I can determine missing payloads by handling "ResolveSource" but that doesn't happen until right before the application in installed.

I deserialize the BootstrapperApplicationData.xml file first thing so I have information about which MSIs MIGHT be installed, but it still doesn't help me determine the source of the MSIs.

Does anyone know how to determine the local path to a payload?

EDIT: Here is an example for how I reference all the installers:

```
<MsiPackage Id="AppName"
      SourceFile="$(var.ProjectName.TargetDir)ProjectName.msi"
      Name="MSI\ProjectName.msi"
      Compressed="no"/>
```

Comment: Are the payloads downloads, already present in loose file, embedded in a detached container or embedded in the attached container? Please show the MsiPackage and Container elements.

Comment: I attached the XML I used to reference the installer above. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `GetLastUsedSourceFolder` function in [cache.cpp](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/burn/engine/cache.cpp), you can see that the engine gets the source folder from the `WixBundleLastUsedSource` variable, and the parent directory of the `WixBundleOriginalSource` variable if `WixBundleLastUsedSource` isn't set.

You can use this along with the `Name` attribute of the `WixPayloadProperties` element in the BootstrapperApplicationData.xml file to predetermine where the engine will look for a payload.  Note that the engine will actually look in the cache first.

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured out that answer yesterday, but this was exactly what I did!

Answer (score 1):

The MSI files are embedded into the bundle .exe and aren't extracted from the bundle until right before the application is installed, which corresponds to when the `ResolveSource` event fires.  However, if you *really* want to get this information, you can programatically extract the MSI files yourself and inspect them using the WiX DTF library (wix.dll in the /bin folder of your WiX install).

```cs
using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml;

private void ExtractEmbeddedMsiInstallers()
{

    var tmpFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
    var bundlePath = Engine.StringVariables["WixBundleOriginalSource"];

    Unbinder unbinder = null;

    try
    {
        unbinder = new Unbinder();

        //The next line will extract the MSIs into the tmpFolder in a subfolder named "AttachedContainer"
        unbinder.Unbind(bundlePath, OutputType.Bundle, tmpFolder);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != unbinder)
            unbinder.DeleteTempFiles();
    }

}
```

You also mentioned needing to inspect data in the MSI database. Here's a sample of how to do that:

```cs
using (var database = new InstallPackage(msiFilePath, DatabaseOpenMode.Transact) { WorkingDirectory = _someTempFolder })
{

    if (database.Tables.Contains("CustomAction"))
    {
        using (View view = database.OpenView("SELECT `Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target` FROM `CustomAction`"))
        {
            view.Execute();
            foreach (Record rowRecord in view)
                using (rowRecord)
                {
                    var actionName = rowRecord.GetString(1);
                    var actionType = rowRecord.GetInteger(2);
                    var binaryName = rowRecord.GetString(3);
                    var methodName = rowRecord.GetString(4);

                    //Do something with the values
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: IF you read my post you would see that my MSIs are not embedded,

Comment: I just tried this code because I do need to extract the MSIs now. I'm getting an error because "winterop.dll" cannot be found at runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: The winterop.dll file is part of the WiX SDK (found in the /bin folder of the WIX installation). You'll need to include it in your `<PayloadGroup>` fragment along side your other dependant assemblies.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe you answered so quickly on a question so old!

Comment: I'm using wix 3.10 and can't seem to find the Unbinder class anywhere. What file are your referencing to be able to access the Unbinder class?

Comment: The `Unbinder` class is part of the `wix.dll` assembly, which should be in the /bin folder of your WiX install. The full class namespace is `Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Unbinder`